# DOORS DXL change outgoing link from current- to a baseline version of a target module

Tags: ibm-doors

A DOORS DXL question:

I have 2 modules, module "Parent" and module "Child". The objects inside module Child is linked to the objects inside module Parent.

Module Parent has several baselines. Instead of linking to the current version of this module, I wish to link to a specific baseline version, for example module Parent baseline 2.0.

A link could be like this:
An object in module Child [current version] --->  An object in module Parent [baseline 2.0]

Could anyone please give me a DXL example?

B.r Tor-Erling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create the link you are looking for on a case by case basis. You would need to supply the Object IDs for each of the links you want to create. If you are trying to update links that already exist, you'll have to loop through all the objects in the Child looking for links to the parent, create the new link to the baseline, then delete the old one.

```
Module mChild = edit("/PROJECT/FOLDER/MODULE_NAME", false)
Module mParent = read("/PROJECT/FOLDER/PARENT_MOD_NAME", false)
Module bParent

Object oChild = object(123, mChild)
Object oParent

String linkMod = "/PROJECT/FOLDER/LINK_MODULE"

  // baseline(MAJ, MIN, SUFFIX) e.g. 2.0
Baseline b = baseline(2, 0, "")

if(baselineExists(mParent, b))
{
  bParent = load(mParent, b, false)
  oParent = object(456, bParent)

  oChild -> linkMod -> oParent

  save mChild
  close bParent
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you @Steve Valliere. All I did was to detail my own modules. In line 8 I changed to: string linkMod (small s). The script then run perfect!